XSLT for-each going outside of main node
Looks like when I do xsl:for-each select="//MeetingPollingParts" I am falling out of my data and going outside of the select="//MeetingPollingQuestion". Do I need to do any to only get the data from that node?
XSLT
<xsl:template match="//ArrayOfMeetingPollingQuestion">
  <xsl:for-each select="//MeetingPollingQuestion">
    <div class="portlet box blue sortable page-break-before: always" style="page-break-after: always;border: 1px solid #0265A6;">
      <div class="portlet-title" style="background-color: #0265A6;min-height:41px">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="MeetingPollingQuestionTypeId = 2">
            <div class="caption">
              <i class="fa fa-th"></i>Multiple Choice
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body" style="background-color: #fff;padding: 15px;">
              <xsl:for-each select="//MeetingPollingParts">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="MeetingPollingPartsTypeId = 1">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <xsl:value-of select="MeetingPollingPartsValues/MeetingPollingPartsValues/QuestionValue" disable-output-escaping="yes"/
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="MeetingPollingPartsTypeId = 3">
                    <xsl:for-each select="MeetingPollingPartsValues">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="radio"></input>
                              <label>
                              <xsl:value-of select="MeetingPollingParts/MeetingPollingParts/MeetingPollingPartsValues/MeetingPollingPartsValues/QuestionValue" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

XML
<ArrayOfMeetingPollingQuestion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <MeetingPollingQuestion>
    <MeetingPollingQuestionId>267</MeetingPollingQuestionId>
    <MeetingPollingId>36</MeetingPollingId>
    <MeetingPollingQuestionTypeId>2</MeetingPollingQuestionTypeId>
    <SequenceOrder>4</SequenceOrder>
    <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
    <MeetingPollingParts>
      <MeetingPollingParts>
        <MeetingPollingPartsId>810</MeetingPollingPartsId>
        <MeetingPollingPartsTypeId>1</MeetingPollingPartsTypeId>
        <MeetingPollingQuestionId>267</MeetingPollingQuestionId>
        <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
          <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>1379</MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsId>0</MeetingPollingPartsId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>1</MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>
            <QuestionValue>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:14.0pt;font-family:'Calibri',sans-serif;"&gt;1. Should zanubrutinib/venetoclax/obinutuzumab be included as a 1L option &lt;em&gt;for&amp;nbsp;all patients&lt;/em&gt; with classical &lt;em&gt;TP53&lt;/em&gt;&amp;nbsp;mutated MCL?&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</QuestionValue>
            <FileManagerId>0</FileManagerId>
          </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
        </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
      </MeetingPollingParts>
      <MeetingPollingParts>
        <MeetingPollingPartsId>811</MeetingPollingPartsId>
        <MeetingPollingPartsTypeId>3</MeetingPollingPartsTypeId>
        <MeetingPollingQuestionId>267</MeetingPollingQuestionId>
        <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
          <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>1380</MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsId>0</MeetingPollingPartsId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>3</MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>
            <QuestionValue>Yes</QuestionValue>
            <FileManagerId>0</FileManagerId>
          </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
          <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>1381</MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsId>0</MeetingPollingPartsId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>3</MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>
            <QuestionValueQuestionValue>No</QuestionValue>
            <FileManagerId>0</FileManagerId>
          </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
          <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>1382</MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsId>0</MeetingPollingPartsId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>3</MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>
            <QuestionValue>Abstain</QuestionValue>
            <FileManagerId>0</FileManagerId>
          </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
        </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
      </MeetingPollingParts>
      <MeetingPollingParts>
        <MeetingPollingPartsId>812</MeetingPollingPartsId>
        <MeetingPollingPartsTypeId>4</MeetingPollingPartsTypeId>
        <MeetingPollingQuestionId>267</MeetingPollingQuestionId>
        <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
          <MeetingPollingPartsValues>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>1383</MeetingPollingPartsValuesId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsId>0</MeetingPollingPartsId>
            <MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>4</MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId>
            <QuestionValue>Is Required</QuestionValue>
            <FileManagerId>0</FileManagerId>
          </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
        </MeetingPollingPartsValues>
      </MeetingPollingParts>
    </MeetingPollingParts>
  </MeetingPollingQuestion>
</ArrayOfMeetingPollingQuestion>


The expression //MeetingPollingParts selects all MeetingPollingParts elements in the entire input document, regardless of the current context. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev.

I suggest you forget about the use of //, it is neither needed in a match pattern nor it is needed in a select attribute of a for-each where you are trying to select a child element of the context node (defined by the outer template or an outer for-each). If you have a specific need to go down from the context node to arbitrary levels of descendants use descendant::foo or .//foo but certainly never //foo.
